# maven release plugin, git, and the pom's not at the top 

Tags: git, maven-2

I've got a git repo where the top level directory has three directories in it: java, COM, and csharp. As you might guess, the pom.xml lives in the java directory.

All is well until I go to run the release plugin. It clones the entire repo into target/checkout, and then expects the pom to be right there at the top. It ain't. End of story.

Can I tell the release plugin about the extra directory, or do I have to split the repro?

Comment: Untested: maybe pomFileName is your friend?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tested: add the following to your build/plugins section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>perform</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <pomFileName>subdir/pom.xml</pomFileName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Where "subdir" is the relative path to the directory where the pom.xml resides.

This works, at least with Maven 3.0.3.  May work with different release plugin versions, but this is untested.

This works with Maven 3.0.4 and maven-release-plugin 2.5 and git 1.8.x.

Comment: Works also on Maven 2.2.1 (with maven-release-plugin:2.2.1). But why do we have to define the `pomFileName` under `executions` hierarchy and not directly under `configuration`. Awfully lots of stuff there for single line of configuration?

Comment: Well, the reason I put it under `executions` was to target the configuration to the specific goal.  If you're sure it won't interfere with other goals, it would probably work directly in `configuration`.

Comment: Whilst this appears to work with maven 3.0.4, it doesn't commit changes to Git repository. Using the latest release plugin does commit changes, but doesn't recognise the pomFileName configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Perfoming release didn't deploy properly in not-root directory with maven-release-plugin version 2.4 (with both maven 3.0.3 and 3.0.4). Downgrading to maven-release-plugin version 2.2.1 fixed the problem.

Comment: using maven 3.0.4, it didn't work also with version 2.1 (inherited from sonatype OSS pom). I had to use 2.2.1 as well.