# Maven deploy fails on Maven parent project

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a maven project with the following hierarchy as created with NetBeans:

```
 root/
       Parent/
              pom.xml
              Project 1/
                        pom.xml
              Project 2/
                        pom.xml
              ....
              Project x/
                        pom.xml
```

When I try the release:perform it fails when attempting to deploy:

```
 [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]   
    [ERROR]   The project  (C:\checkout\pom.xml) has 1 error
    [ERROR]     Non-readable POM C:\checkout\pom.xml: C:\checkout\pom.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

It looks like the plugin expects the pom to be on the root folder. I was unable to find a customization point on the plug-in to specify the pom.xml location.

Is this not possible, or did I organize the project wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching on the net I found [this post](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Release-plugin-when-POM-is-not-in-root-directory-td4956364.html) which pointed me to a question with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558785/maven-release-plugin-git-and-the-poms-not-at-the-top).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to run `mvn release:perform` from your checkout root directory, while you should `cd` to `Parent` instead.

I assume that your project is indeed stored under Subversion or some other Maven-supported version control tool and that you checked it out in your `C:\checkout` directory.

Comment: I ran the release:perform goal from the parent folder, and yes, I'm using Mercurial. is just that the repository layout is as described in the question when the plug-in does the checkout, the pom is not in the root folder.

Comment: But do you have a `Parent` folder in `C:\checkout` or is `C:\checkout` the direct parent folder of your `Project` folders?

Comment: Parent folder is Simple Marauroa Parent. I'm testing the way specified referenced answer on my own answer.